# .bat to stop windows Update

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-services

I have gotten tired of searching how to stop Windows Updates from running permanently in Windows 10 since every after a restart it runs again. It came to my mind that maybe I could make a .bat file that could stop the windows update in the services so that I could just click it every time I turn on my laptop.

I have known of the `sc` `start/stop` `serviceName`. My question is, what is the name of the Windows Update service? Because when I type in windows update in in the `serviceName`, it would show that the service is not installed.

Comment: Probably a better question for SuperUser.

Comment: Next time please ask such a question on [Super User](https://superuser.com). However, you can see the service name by starting __Services__, scroll in list of services down to __Windows Update__, double click on the service to open the properties window for the service and read on tab __General__ the first line __Service name__ displaying `wuauserv` (on Windows 7).

Comment: [This is the best awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44555537/7811302) it is power shell script to stop updates easy enough to make into a batch script

Answer (score 4):

simple batch which you can even put into your Run at start up. This one works on Windows 8 and older should perhaps work on Windows 10 as well.

```
@echo off
net stop "Windows Update"
```

You can also stop it together with the background downloading processes.
This one works on windows 10

```
@echo off
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
net stop dosvc
```

Comment: how to undo this? (using batch file)

Comment: And how can i ensure that your solution works properly?

Answer (score 2):

The name of your service is `wuauserv`.

If you want to get a list of display names with their associated service names you can do so relatively quickly by utilising `WMIC` at your Command prompt.

```dos
WMIC /Output:Services.txt Service Get DisplayName,Name&&Services.txt
```

The `Services.txt` file will be located in the Command prompt's current directory.

Answer (score 1):

The powershell commands to :-

Stop Windows update is:
Stop-Service wuauserv (Run as admin)

Start Windows update is:
Start-Service wuauserv

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the LAN wire or disconnect your system from the internet as soon as possible. Write "Services.msc" in a run (Windows key + R), then scroll down and search Windows update option there. Double click on that, select the startup type "disabled" then click ok, it will stop the windows update and also fix blue screen problems during upgrade on Windows 10.