# Programmatically Disable-ScheduledTask For Windows Update on Build 16299

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with a script.

On previous build of windows 10 I have been able to use the following script to disable windows 10 Updates:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\" | Disable-ScheduledTask 

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\" | Disable-ScheduledTask 

stop-service wuauserv
```

Upon trying to update this on Build 16299 the disable commands fail with the following exception:

> Get-ScheduledTask : The system cannot find the file specified.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTas
>      k], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Get-ScheduledTask

A work around I found is to use [PSExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to open the `TaskScheduler`:

```
psexec.exe -i -s -accepteula %windir%\system32\mmc.exe /s taskschd.msc
```

However this requires manually disabling each of the 13 services in each folder.

My next thought would be to combine the two into a .net app but I was wondering if anyone has a fix for the powershell commands.  I'm assuming windows is now using some type of alias for the the task paths ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following [PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790849)

```
#Disable Windows Update
$WindowsUpdatePath = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\"
$AutoUpdatePath = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"

If(Test-Path -Path $WindowsUpdatePath) {
    Remove-Item -Path $WindowsUpdatePath -Recurse
}

New-Item $WindowsUpdatePath -Force
New-Item $AutoUpdatePath -Force

Set-ItemProperty -Path $AutoUpdatePath -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\" | Disable-ScheduledTask

takeown /F C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator /A /R
icacls C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator /grant Administrators:F /T

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\" | Disable-ScheduledTask

Stop-Service wuauserv
Set-Service wuauserv -StartupType Disabled

Write-Output "All Windows Updates were disabled" -ForegroundColor Green
```