# Automate Disabling Windows Update using Powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to Automate Disabling Windows Update using Powershell.

The setting i need to do to achieve this is:

> • Go to Run-> services.msc •  Select windows update -> Disable it
>
> • Check for updates -> Pause updates -> Enabled

Is there a Powershell command/way of automating these manual steps for doing these OS settings.

Comment: which version of PoSh do you need this for? you have v2 & v3 tagged ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off windows update service & auto updates windows 10 using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555223/turn-off-windows-update-service-auto-updates-windows-10-using-powershell)

Answer (score 3):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/security-updates/windowsupdateservices/18127499#automatic-update-configuration-options--